# Accessing UI in Threading

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, user-interface

In My applicaion i have `grid` and `picturebox`.I want to show the picture box when am loading a grid and some process.I am trying like this

```
Dim mRestoreThread as thread
```

Before LoadDataGrid Invoked set `PictureBox1.Visible=true`

```
  mRestoreThread = New Thread(AddressOf LoadDataGrid)
  mRestoreThread.IsBackground = True
  mRestoreThread.Start()
```

After this method finished then  set `PictureBox1.Visible=false`

(This Picturebox is show for the processing going on)

How to achecive this?.Any feasible solution is there?

Comment: You're setting the picturebox to visible for the period of time it takes to start the thread - you're not waiting for it to signal that it has finished, in the code above?

Comment: @RowlandShaw How do i get singal from that thread that it has been finished?

Comment: Is the code you posted running on the UI, I assume it is?  Where does the cross thread error occur(show that code)?

Comment: @dbasnett i find the cross thread error and solve it.In side the loaddatagrid function am setting the currow.

Comment: Your problem is resolved?

Comment: @dbasnett Not yet. My main Problem is show picture box when this method is ivoked. after finished that function the picture box is visible false

Comment: Tell me the reason for down vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub LoadDataGrid()
    'do whatever here
    '
    '
    'at the end do
    Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf hidePB))
End Sub

Private Sub hidePB()
    PictureBox1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

There are shorter ways.

Comment: Thanks for valuable time. But its not work.picturebox is not visible when loaddatadrive invoked.

Comment: After setting PictureBox1.Visible=true, try PictureBox1.Refresh.

Comment: It is wroking. the picture box is visible . but one problem. in my picture box i have animated image its not animated.

Comment: Sounds like a different issue.  Ask a new question, and post the code that is supposed to animate it.